# Will dismissing a vc before a DispatchGroup finishes crash the app?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I know that you have to balance out the calls with `DispatchGroup` for both `.enter()` and `.leave()`.

The question is if I started a `dispatchGroup.enter()` and I `dismissed/popped` the vc before the calls were balanced, would the app crash? Basically, would `deinit()` change the outcome because the vc is no longer in memory?

eg. This starts, but before the 3rd background task is completed, the vc is dismissed or popped. `.leave()` only ran twice but it's supposed to run 3 times. This is just a simple example to get the idea across:

```
func viewDidLoad()

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    // there are 3 background tasks
    for task in backgroundTasks {

        group.enter()
        someBackgroundTask(... completion: { (_) in

            group.leave()
        })
    }
    group.notify...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, failing to call `leave` will not, itself, cause a crash. (It likely is not relevant here, but calling `leave` too many times will crash.)

What will happen, though, is that until all of the `enter` calls are offset by `leave` calls, the dispatch group will not be released. Worse, anything captured strongly by the completion handler and the `notify` closures will not get released. So you really do want to ensure that all `enter` calls are eventually offset by `leave` calls.

But I would first suggest confirming that `leave` is not getting called enough times. Typically the exact opposite problem occurs, that `leave` *is* called the correct number of times, but that one or more of these background tasks finish after the view controller was dismissed, and does not handle this scenario gracefully.

---

For what it is worth, if `someBackgroundTask` is doing something that is no longer needed after the view controller is dismissed, we would:

- make `someBackgroundTask` a cancelable task, if possible;
- make sure the various closures do not maintain a strong reference back to the view controller (by using `[weak self]` pattern), eliminating strong reference cycles;
- make sure the closure gracefully handles if the view controller is deallocated by the time the closure runs, e.g.

  ```
  group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
      guard let self = self else { return }

      ...
  }
  ```

  and
- in `deinit` of the view controller (or somewhere equivalent) cancel the tasks that are no longer needed (again, assuming it is a cancelable task).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I always use `[weak self]` and `guard let self = self else { return }` inside all of my closures. I actually can’t cancel the tasks because they are really a series of Firebase calls to get data for the datasource eg `postRef > blockedRef > usersRef > append(post); cv.reloadData()`. There is a chance that by the time cv.reloadData() is called the user already popped the vc. There isn’t a way to cancel anything in this situation. If I understand correctly `[weak self] guard let self = self {return}` are what’s really going to prevent any problems here. Correct?

Comment: *So you really do want to ensure that all enter calls are eventually offset by leave calls.* How can you prevent someone from popping a vc? The only way that I can think of is to hide the backButton or cancelButton but the user can also swipe to dismiss or pop. Hiding either until the data is received seems like bad ux though. Imagine a scenario where they have a bad connection and the ref calls are taking forever, they can't leave the vc

Comment: We'd never stop them from dismissing. If the tasks is non-cancelable, we'd just let it go, do the `[weak self]` and `guard let self = ...` trick and call it a day. But if you're correct that you're already doing that (in both the completion handler and the `notify` closure), then it's not clear why it would crash. It's inefficient, but should work. Edit question to include stack trace and/or crash log. Let's identify the precise source of the crash. But the issue is not that you had three `enter` and two `leave` calls.

Comment: actually there hasn't been a crash as of yet because my internet connection is really fast and because I'm doing the calls in viewDidLoad, by the time the vc appears, everything is already finished. **I wasn't sure what would happen in a scenario with a bad connection, that's why I asked**. I have an idea to create a scenario, when I try it if a crash occurs I'll update the question and send you a message. As usual THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: You can use network link conditioner (either on macOS when using simulator or on physical device in developer settings) to simulate slower connections.

Comment: I never heard of that before. Can you paste a link with some info about it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/422/